# Create a Public SQL Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server

I have a testing environment that I would like my team members to access just to develop on. It is not linked to any other server system or network, however it is open to the Internet. What I would like to know is it possible to make the SQL Server public so that my team members can connect to an run code?

Currently it is not possible for them to VPN.

Setup:

Windows 2008 Server

SQL Server 2012

Comment: This will allow anyone to attempt to log into the SQL Server instance.  This includes people who will attempt to break into the SQL Server instance.

Comment: Why can't they VPN? The 2008 server can be used as a VPN server if that's what you need.

Comment: I haven't set up VPN on this server. Which leads to my next question. I have the server role setup but the client are unable to connect, even internally. They get error 807. Any thoughts?

Comment: ^ Start a new question for your VPN issues so they get the proper attention from the right folks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply make the port 1433 available for through your router. Should be all you need. Well, that's the minimum you need, but it answers your question. :)

1. [Hole in router/firewall for 1433](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_pinhole).
2. [Port forwarded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) in router to push traffic on 1433 to [IP of SQL Server]
3. [Exception in Windows Firewall to allow traffic to port 1433](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175043.aspx) (TCP).
4. Confirmation that [SQL is configured to allow connections by TCP/IP.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177440.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using a non-standard port, something other than 1433. See [Configure a Server to Listen on a Specific TCP Port](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177440.aspx). Port 1433 is subject to constant brute force attack scans from bots trying for weak sa passwords.

Comment: You can configure something like 1334 which is memorable, but less likely to be subject to brute force attacks.

Comment: To simplify things have the firewall port forward from a non-standard port. Same result and no changes needed on the SQL Server.